# Connection pooling with URLConnection?

Tags: java, android

I've just read the android article about http client options. I'd like to start using HttpsURLConnection, how does one enable connection pooling for it? The article says that is possible, but doesn't explain how.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

Ideally the pooling would cut down on response time for my http requests.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's enabled by default. See the docs for some details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems they disabled pooling by setting `http.keepAlive=false`, which brings `System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "true");` should enable pooling. But I don't think this is better approach unless you have same data.