# Android: HttpURLConnection or sockets?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have an Android App that calls a URL every 2 seconds.
This drains battery, I know. But I need the connection because there must always be a connection between the app and the webserver.

Now my question: is it better for performance and battery to realise this with "HttpURLConnection " every 2 seconds or with a socket.
If socket, which socket? Asynctask, thread, websocket, or using this way?:
[Socket Programming using android and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863610/socket-programming-using-android-and-php)

Comment: Even if you do that every two seconds does not imply that there is always a connection as http is a connectionless protocol. The connection is closed after every request. So explain better what you need.

Comment: @greenapps See my answer. See if it needs improvement :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are targeting Android 2.3 or higher definitly use URLConnection;
For Android versions below consider Apache HttpClient;

See this link for further information [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Both (if used correctly) maintain sessions in background and use ConnectionPooling which helps you avoid the overhead of establishing a  new TCP session every time. URLConnection is highly optimized on newer android version and probably most suited for your challange.

On ConnectionPooling consider this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714396/connection-pooling-with-urlconnection)

Don't use sockets for http, as the provided http clients are highly optimized (e.g. URLConnection uses compression if possible); sockets are ONLY relevant when you need to access different protocols...

Comment: And should you need an idea of how well `HttpUrlConnection` is lightweight and optimized, just have a look at the source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/refs/heads/master/luni/src/main/java/java/net/HttpURLConnection.java

Answer (score 1):

In my limited knowledge,

`Socket` would increase the complexity unnecessarily. Stick to `HttpURLConnection`.

As for when to release the connection,
do it when your application loses focus like in `onPause()` or `onResume()` and reconnect when it gains focus.

Answer (score 1):

You are going in very wrong direction. if you want to listen any change on server every 2sec just let the server manage this thing.You can use XMPP or modify push notification for this purpose. If you want some data from server after every 2 sec you can use payload with push notification which allow you with 4k of data with every notification